# Unable to connect to SQL server from linux pyodbc

Tags: python, linux, odbc, pyodbc, pymssql

Below is the error while connecting to SQL server from linux:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(connect_string)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', u"[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
Details in odbcinst -j

odbcinst -j

unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Comment: It appears you have a driver missing. Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/651460/cant-connect-to-ms-sql-with-pyodbc

Comment: Above link and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 should be helpful for you.

Comment: I have installed driver: [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib

Comment: @RangaraguNivas - Which flavour of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';uid='+username+';pwd='+ password)
```

Where "{/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.3.so.1.1}" is your driver that you need to find in your system.

"/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib"

Comment: Segmentation fault (core dumped) getting this error cxnn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0};SERVER={localhost};DATABASE={test};uid={user};pwd={1234}')

Comment: but your libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0 is in /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/ ???

Comment: yes libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0 is in /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/

Comment: check the odbc.ini  and odbcinst.ini    https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Drivers-and-Driver-Managers

Comment: cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=2

[ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0
Threading=1
UsageCount=1

I have updated as below 
cat /etc/odbc.ini

Decription = ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
Driver = /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0

Comment: I think maybe you have forgotten some of these steps in the installation:    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: NAME="CentOS Linux"

Comment: I reinstalled drivers and getting below error:    pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: console : telnet IP_Server_SQL 1433

Comment: Telnet is not working on Linux. I did ping SQL_IP and getting a response. no errors